# save and automatically open the containing folder in windows 7

Tags: windows, user-interface, outlook, contextmenu, outlook-addin

I use windows 7 and I would like that when a file is saved, it opens automatically the containing folder of the saved file with the saved file already selected and highlighted. 
For example when I save an attachment of MS Outlook message, I always do something with the file after I save it. I would like to get an explorer window opened for my next operation. 
Can this be done with an OS or outlook add-on? for example in the context menu an option "save and open the containing folder". How would I do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can launch Windows Explorer and select a given file using the following command line

```
explorer.exe /select "c:\folder\My test file.msg"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Process.Start](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.start%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method to open the Windows explorer window programmatically. For example in C# the following command will open the D drive:

```
Process.Start("explorer D:");
```